# nginx rewrite exclude subdomains

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to redirect:

`http://*.example.com/list/`

to

```
http://demo.example.com/list/
```

excluding from rewrite rule links:

```
xxx.example.com/list/
yyy.example.com/list/
zzz.example.com/list/
```

This should be a regex, right?.. But i'm newbie here. Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .example.com;

    location /list/ {
        if ($host !~ ^(xxx|yyy|zzz)\.example\.com) {
            return 301 http://demo.example.com/list/;
        }
        # ....
    }
}
```